# How to insert a new cell in between UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collections, family-tree

How to insert a new cell in between `UITableViewCell`s when a cell gets selected from the `UICollectionView`? Here is what it would look like:

I am trying to create a family tree(pedigree chart).when the parent is selected it shows a Detail and the childs. How to achieve this?
Thank You!

Comment: YOURTABLE.beginUpdates()
 YOURTABLE.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: YOURINSERTROWPOSITION, section: 0)], with: .automatic) // that means add here your row before you want to add. like 1 2 3 4 5 what ever
 YOURTABLE.endUpdates()

Comment: Add data inside array which you are returning in numOfRows and reload it.Implement all thing inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Thanks for the reply. How to insert a **view** in between two cell? as shown in the above figure?

Comment: @Shibili create one tableviewcell or that show your viewcell that white color in your snapshot and when button click at time insert that cell in tableview so your problem solve

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya can you please explain more about this? Thank you!

Comment: i want to show your tableview cell Cellrowatindex delegates method  that display tableview in that tableview you display collectionview

Comment: I have created two different XIB files. One for the Detail and other for the collection view.Both of the cell loads using XIB. @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: then create another xib for your popup view and just load that xib when you need to display on collectionviewcell click

Comment: YOURTABLE.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: YOURINSERTROWPOSITION, section: 0)], with: .automatic). How to insert that XIB at  a perticular index of the table view? @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: just create tableview cellrowatindexpathmethod that inside put one condition for popviewxib cell if you want to display it then write code inside it otherwise return anothercell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (...)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPaths], with: .top)
}
```

Comment: When ever a collection view cell is selected a **Detail view** will pop up in between the table view cells as shown in the image above. How to insert a view in between the two cells? @MichałKwiecień . Thanks in advance!